# Android - app has been rejected because it is primarily child-directed

Tags: android

I made an app in Adobe Animate for Kids which was accepted 1st time and after some days I added Admob ads in my app and did not change anything except this. But now my app is not accepting on play store and first release is still online.

Can anyone guide me what issue can be here. This is my app id air.com.ejaz.kidsabc

and this is the email which i received on rejection on 2nd release

> Thanks for submitting your app to Google Play. I reviewed KidsABC
>   Learn, air.com.ejaz.kidsabc, and had to reject it because your Play
>   Store listing suggests your app may be primarily directed to children
>   under the age of 13 as defined by COPPA. Apps that are primarily
>   child-directed must opt-in to the Designed for Families program. If
>   you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still
>   live on Google Play.
>
> Here's how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> Read through the Primarily Child-Directed Declaration policy on our
>   Developer Policy Center. Sign in to your Developer Console to confirm
>   your Child-Directed Declaration on the Pricing & distribution page. If
>   your app is primarily child-directed:
>
> Update your Primarily Child-Directed Declaration on the Developer
>   Console. Opt-in to the Designed for Families program. You can find
>   general information and answers to frequently asked questions about
>   Designed for Families on the Android Developers site. Make sure your
>   app is compliant with the Designed for Families program requirements.
>   Apps that declare they are primarily child directed but do not meet
>   Designed for Families requirements will be removed from the store.
>   Submit your app. If your app is not primarily child-directed and you
>   feel this rejection may have been in error, please reach out to our
>   policy support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within
>   2 business days.

Thank

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 9):

This is a new question that google have introduced recently and needs to be answered. follow these steps below:

- Go to the google play console
- Go to your app
- Go to "Store Presence"
- Go To "pricing and Distribution"
- You will find a **New** question in there about Targeting toward children which will be unanswered.

Question: Is your app primarily directed towards children under the age of 13 as defined by COPPA ?

- Answer the question and "Submit update"

You will then be able to submit your app

Answer (score 0):

I Have Check Your [App On Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.ejaz.kidsabc) Which Contains The Design and metadata which is child oriented So you must have to change in the app's prices & app distribution Tab in developer console

Check The Primarily Child-Directed As YES but make sure you have change the adloading method inside your app/game because your app contains ads

[How To Target App As Family Directed](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting) For More Details [Read This](https://play.google.com/about/families/coppa-compliance/child-directed/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new program policy that you need to opt-in to designed for family, so if your app is primarily for children then you need to opt-in to DFF. And if your app is already opt-in then there will be No Fill ads from Admob.